# SQLite database for heavy read only production website

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a Ruby on Rails web application that will require about 50 writes to the database to configure itself. Then the rest of the life of the application it will be involved with reading the database. The database will have around 50 rows.

Would a SQLite database be enough to handle this amount of data on a production server that may get up to 100 thousand hits an hour? Or would it be wise to go with MySQL server? (Also is it possible to ask Ruby on Rails to preload the entire content of the SQLite database into memory?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Would SQLite work? Yes, but it would be slower than a dedicated PostGreSQL or MySQL database. You can't really get around that. Honestly, if your database is so small and you're worried about speed, use reddis or another in memory solution. With a SQL solution, you could also do one giant read at application startup and throw it in memory using memcache or redis. But redis is persistent so if you went that route, you could just use redis and avoid SQL all together.